# Replace the subquery with JOIN/APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, apply

I have the following SQL.

```
SELECT t0.QustionId, t1.QuestionText, t2.AnswerText FROM
ActiveQuestion AS t0
INNER JOIN Question AS t1
    ON t1.QuestionId = ActiveQuestion.QuestionId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Answer AS t2
    ON t2.SectionId = t0.SectionId
    AND t1.ParentId IN 
            (SELECT QuestionId 
                    FROM Question WHERE SharedQuestionId = t2.SharedQeustionId)
```

Questions can be shared (with the same SharedQuestionId), questions can have parent question.

I want get rid of the subquery. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the table `Question` one more time with different alias:

```
SELECT 
  t0.QustionId, 
  t1.QuestionText, 
  t2.AnswerText,
  p.questionI ParentQuestionId
FROM ActiveQuestion      AS t0
INNER JOIN Question      AS t1  ON t1.QuestionId      = ActiveQuestion.QuestionId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Answer   AS t2  ON t2.SectionId       = t0.SectionId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Question AS  p  ON t1.ParentId        = p.QuestionId 
                               AND p.SharedQuestionId = t2.SharedQeustionId;
```

Comment: @Mahmound, the original query use the subquery to limit the result set in Answer (t2), the new sproc doesn't.

Comment: @Icerman It should work the same way and it will limit the result set with `AND p.SharedQuestionId = t2.SharedQeustionId`, can you please post some sample data for three tables explaining this issue. It will be helpful.

Comment: @Mahmound, I verified using sample datd. Thanks!